# When I submit a form in django (or access admin) the address changes in URL bar to an ip address

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following set up.

On my dns: 
an A name record that points my domain to an IP addres

On my server:
nginx -> gunicorn -> django

But when I submit a form (e.g. log in form) the address in the URL bar changes from my domain name to my IP address. This causes a Cross Domain Error.

This happens on forms and when I access mydomain/admin

when I access pages my domain name in the URL bar remains intact. When I go to mydomain/admin it automatically switches to the IP w/o submitting any other forms. Any other time I have to submit a form for it to change to the IP address.

All my media and everything use mydomain in the path. It is the strangest thing. I only first noticed it when I went to my admin page, but didnt think much of it. But I just added a few forms and now I can't submit the forms because the forms try to submit to the IP address causing the cross domain error.

I should add teh forms are auto generated by django-registration.

Answer (score 0):

Look for your IP in your `settings.py` file. It could be a setting like `MEDIA_URL` set to use your IP and not your domain.

Comment: No IP addresses are in any file. except my database's IP

Answer (score 0):

This has to mean that your forms are configured to submit to the IP address. Look at the source of your form and look for the form tag:

```
<form action="http://(ip here?)/form/" method="GET">
```

Make sure that IP address isn't inserted there. You could use a relative URL. I normally leave it blank since most of my forms are processed by the same view that generated the form to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you were developing locally at some point and this did not occur so I'd suggest it's something in your Nginx config. Can you use Firebug/Web Inspector to see if there's any redirects happening from your domain to your IP?

I'd also check to make sure that your Site's URL is correctly set up in the admin. Sometimes this can cause incorrect urls although I don't think the cases you've mentioned apply.